# Meteor Angular & Request - How to bind?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to finish the last phase of my script, which is displaying the response. I have a Meteor method that requests, through basic auth, an object from Zendesk's API. This method is called by Meteor.call() within my client section. I can log the response, but am unable to get it to bind and display.

Here is my js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    // This code only runs on the client
    angular.module('equationKPIs', ['angular-meteor']);

    angular.module('equationKPIs').controller('EquationKPICtrl', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {

            Meteor.call("zendeskUnsolvedTickets", function (error, results) {
                var json = JSON.parse(results);
                $scope.metrics = [{
                    'name': 'Unsolved Tickets',
                    'value': json.view_count.pretty
                }];
                console.log($scope.metrics);
            });

        }]);
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        zendeskUnsolvedTickets: function () {
            var request = Meteor.npmRequire('request'),
                username = '',
                password = '',
                url = 'https://equationconsulting.zendesk.com/api/v2/views/',
                auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

            var options = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': auth
                }
            };

            var tickets = Async.runSync(function (done) {
                options.url = url + '32396347/count.json';
                request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (error) throw new Error(error);
                    done(null, body);
                });
            });

            return tickets.result;
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="container"
     ng-app="equationKPIs"
     ng-controller="EquationKPICtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="metric in metrics">
        <h4>{{metric.name}}</h4>
        <h2>{{metric.value}}</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

I've tried a few iterations of the js, such as:

```
$scope.metrics = Meteor.call("zendeskUnsolvedTickets", function (error, results) {
            var json = JSON.parse(results);
            var response = [{
                'name': 'Unsolved Tickets',
                'value': json.view_count.pretty
            }];
            return response;
        });
```

Any insight on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `$scope.$apply()` since you are assigning to `$scope` outside the context of Angular (inside the ajax callback)

```
Meteor.call("zendeskUnsolvedTickets", function (error, results) {
  var json = JSON.parse(results);
  $scope.metrics = [{
    'name': 'Unsolved Tickets',
    'value': json.view_count.pretty
  }];
  console.log($scope.metrics);
  $scope.$apply(); // this here
});
```

More [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! Just out of curiosity, is this a proper setup for this process? I've read that Meteor.methods should be used for CUD and get requests like this should be handled by some other means, such as publish/subscribe.

Comment: I don't know much about Meteor but it's an anti-pattern to make ajax calls inside the Controller. Instead you should create a service/factory with a simpler API so all this (Meteor, etc) would just become an implementation detail that the Controller is not aware of. Same thing goes if you wanna implement a pub/sub interface. Just put it into a factory and inject it into the controller.